# How to read JSON file (Spark/Pyspark) with dots in column names using inferred schema?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I am importing JSON files dynamically (sending multiple file names to a script in parallel) and one of my files includes dots in the field names.

When this gets read into a dataframe for processing, the schema inference breaks it up into nested structs (ie; "A.B.C" -> A [B [C]]).

Is there a way to read in columns from the file without breaking up a column name that includes dots?

I understand that backticks can qualify a column name, but since I cannot explicitly define the schema before reading the JSON file, I cannot do this.

```py
df = sqlContext.read.option('multiline','true').json(<location>)
df.printSchema()
```

I see the field "P.O. Replacement Cost" become:

```py
|-- P: struct (nullable = true)

 |    |-- O: struct (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- Replacement Cost: double (nullable = true)
```

Comment: please post your sample json data

Comment: I would argue the data is not relevant for the issue. I also cannot post it for security reasons. The core of the issue is that I have to read a field named "P.O. Replacement Cost" from a JSON file but cannot call it by custom schema, so how do I dynamically provide a check for dots in a field name.

Answer (score 0):

dot notation within the col function

`col('colName.nestCol.nestNestCol.etc')`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.select( col('colName.nestCol').alias('nestCol') )

df.where( col('colName.nestCol') == 'value')
```

EDIT:
sorry I misread your questions. Try this and see if it works.

```
    .withColumn(
        'p',        # Overwrite your nested struct with the new nested column
        struct(
            col( 'p.*' ),
            lit( col('p.a.b.c') ).alias( 'abc' )  # Renaming
            )
        )\
    .withColumn(
        'p',
        col( 'p' ).dropFields( col('a.b.c') )   # Remove the ugly named column
        )
```

if you don't need to keep the column in the nested struct you can do a simple

```
select( col('p.a.b.c').alias('abc') )
```

This is move the a.b.c column out of the nested struct.